# Cannot convert int(*)[5] to int*

Tags: c++, arrays, data-conversion

When i tried to access array elements using pointer I got this error i don't understand how can i access with the help of pointer.

`Error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[5]’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void addd(int*, int)`

Any guidance on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    void addd(int *ptr,int length)
    {
       cout<<"The values in the array are: ";
       for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          cout<< *ptr <<" ";
          ptr++;
       }
    }
    
    
    int main() {
       int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       
       addd(&arr,5);
       
       //int *ptr = &arr[0];
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The call should be either `addd(arr,5);` or `addd(&arr[0],5);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott - I'd limit that to `addd(arr,5)`, taking the address of the first element (while equivalent) shows a misunderstanding of array/pointer conversion.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I though it would be good to let OP work out why those two are equivalent.

Comment: Both provide the same result, but the first shows an understanding that, on access, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element, while the second uses the *address of* operator to accomplish the same thing. The only reason I mention it is that more times than not, the questions appending the `'&'` to attempt to create a pointer generally show a lack and understanding of both. `:)`.

Comment: I guess the one advantage of using `&arr[0]` is that the code is now interchangeable if or when the OP goes to use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function receives a pointer to `int`, so you should just pass the address of the first element.

You can do that:

```
addd(&arr[0],5);
```

or simply:

```
addd(arr,5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. `&arr` means `int (*)[5]`, but you are using `int *ptr`. So, you've to use like below:

```
addd(arr, 5); // this is correct
// addd(&arr, 5) // this is wrong
```

Here, `arr` is passed as `int *`

Comment: NOOOO. `&arr` is `int (*)[5]` which is NOT the same as `int**`. With `int **p;`, `p+1` advances `size (a_pointer)` number of bytes. with `int (*p)[5];` `p+1` advances `sizeof arr` bytes (20-bytes).

Comment: No worries -- that's not the first time I've seen that one `:)`

Comment: `int (*)[N]` is subtly different from `int (*)[]`, so I wouldn't omit the size.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Thanks for your valuable comment. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array to a function, for example:

```
addd(arr,5);
```

then the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, an `int*`. Instead of relying on the implicit conversion, you can make it explicit:

```
addd( &arr[0],5);
   //      ^-  first element
   // ^------  address-of first element
```

However, arrays are not pointers and taking the address of the array yields a pointer to an array:

```
using pointer_to_array = int (*)[5];
pointer_to_array p = &arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

arrays and pointers are pretty much inter-related to each other. An array by default points to the address of the first element, that is the element at index 0. So, working with arrays and pointers are pretty much the same thing( not every time ). So, you do not need to pass on the array as

```
addd(&arr,5);
```

you should simply do just

```
addd(arr,5);
```

Also , i will say,
The statement
`addd(&arr[0],5);` does the job, but not a good way to proceed.